# WYSIWYG editor: how to control number of characters a user can editor?

Tags: javascript, java, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG input box in a web interface. I am hoping to limit the number of characters (not HTML tag-related characters that are generated by the editor) a user can enter.

What are the approaches to this need? No matter whether it is done client side (Javascript) or server side (I use Java on the server-side), it seems to be quite a complex program. Is there any solution I can reuse?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You can attempt to use a regular expression to ignore any html tags, but it wouldn't be perfect.

Comment: can put the data into a document fragment and get the text value and count that